# innerHTML with added script

Tags: javascript

I have the below code:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function checker () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("project") > -1) {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "CONTAINS KEYWORD";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'no keyword';
    }
    setInterval(checker,1000);
});
</script>
```

This checks to see if the URL contains the word "project" and if so displays "contains keyword". If it does not is shows "no keyword". It also keeps checking for this every second.

The problem is I need to replace "CONTAINS KEYWORD" with :

```
 <tr>
  <td  align="right"><a onClick="javascript:addURL(this);" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?src=sp&u=" target="new"><img src="http://example.co.uk/planner-files/facebook.png"></a></td>
  <td  align="left"><a onClick="javascript:addURL(this);" href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Check out my kitchen design http://example.co.uk/planner-files/kitchen-share.jpg&hashtags=example&url="  target="_blank"><img src="http://example.co.uk/planner-files/twitter.png"></a></td>
</tr>
```

I'm used to php where you would add e.g. a / before the " etc but I don't know how I can get around this with .

Any ideas? If possible, please include examples.

Comment: While the `onClick` implementation could certainly be avoided with a delegated handler, the statement `Obviously this doesn't work since its script in script.` is simply untrue. With some quotation escaping I see no reason why you couldn't just copy+paste this directly into the `innerHTML`, though again, I'm not advocating for that as a practice.

Comment: could you give me an example of 1 line?

Comment: `<tr>` element should be child element of `<table>` element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much easier for you to toggle the visibility of the markup you want instead of rendering it each time the condition is evaluated.

I'd create a class that hides by default:

```
<style type="text/css">.hidden{ display: none; }</style>
```

Then all you need to do is add or remove the class from the test div:

```
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');
var hasProjectInURL = location.href.indexOf('project') > -1;
testDiv.className = hasProjectInURL ? '' : 'hidden';
```

Comment: Any chance you could provide a fiddle of the above (doesn't need to use all my <tr> can just be "example text" ? e.g. with the setInterval

Comment: you would just have your tr stuff inside the div with the id of test

Comment: `function checker () {
var testDiv = document.getElementById('test');
var hasProjectInURL = location.href.indexOf('project') > -1;
testDiv.className = hasProjectInURL ? '' : 'hidden';
}
setInterval(checker,1000);` this works for me, thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to use setInterval, as the location won't change (unless you have code that does that).  You could just run this onload of the document/body.

Comment: sadly the URL changes constantly (its out of my control). e.g. when a project is saved the URL changes to contain the word project.

Comment: Could you give an example of the opposite? e.g. if url doesn't contain show a div called noproject

Comment: it's the same, just chagne the names:  var noProjectDiv = document.getElementById('noproject');  noProjectDiv.className = hasProjectInURL ? 'hidden' : '';// note the inverted values returned